# How to make a folder/directory on a local machine/PC from Google Colab

Tags: deep-learning, directory, google-colaboratory

Actually I am working on a deep learning task on google Colab. I want to read a dataset from google Colab, containing images of cats and dogs which are located on my local drive/PC , and then creating different directories for train, validation, and test images for cats and dogs. How Can I do it from Google colab?

I can do it from my VS Code running on my local drive by using following lines of code but I am confused about how I can do it from Google colab:

```py
import os, shutil

original_dataset_dir = '/Users/fchollet/Downloads/kaggle_original_data'

base_dir = '/Users/fchollet/Downloads/cats_and_dogs_small'
os.mkdir(base_dir)

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
os.mkdir(train_dir)

validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'validation')
os.mkdir(validation_dir)

test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')
os.mkdir(test_dir)

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(train_cats_dir)

train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(train_dogs_dir)

validation_cats_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(validation_cats_dir)

validation_dogs_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(validation_dogs_dir)

test_cats_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(test_cats_dir)

test_dogs_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(test_dogs_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.makedirs` like so.

```
import os, shutil

original_dataset_dir = '/Users/fchollet/Downloads/kaggle_original_data'

# put /content in front because this is is the default location where data
# is stored for the Colab user
base_dir = '/content/Users/fchollet/Downloads/cats_and_dogs_small'  
# Use makedirs and the exist_ok flag
os.makedirs(base_dir, exist_ok = True)

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
os.makedirs(train_dir, exist_ok=True)
```

By default, Colab has its working directory set to `/content` so precede the new folder with this.